# Access many-to-many reverse lookup from @property in model with Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Concordance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    tunes = models.ManyToManyField(MsTune, related_name="concordances")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MsTune(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True) # title (source)
    [etc...]

    @property
    def concordances(self):
        for concordance in self.concordances.all:
            for t in concordance.tunes.all:
                [stuff]
                return '-' + t.name
```

I want then to show that property in my template:

`{{ tune.concordances|safe }}`

My problem is that `self__concordances.all` always appears to be `none` even though there is data. What am I missing? This is what I get output in my template:

`bassculture.Concordance.None`

For the record, this code directly in my template works:

```
{% for concordance in tune.concordances.all %}
{% for t in concordance.tunes.all %}
- {{ t.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What I wanted is to get that data from the @property in the model to see if that speeds up the retrieval process.

Comment: Please specify more details. This code doesn't make sense "as is". Please provide minimal reproducible example, so anyone reading your question can understand your issue.

Comment: why would self__concordances exists, what makes you think of it being anything other than None. Did you mean self.concordances.all ?

Comment: @iklinac `self.concordances.all` is what I had at the beginning and it was `none`, that's why I then tried with `self__concordances.all`.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I'll add some more details in my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the automatic `concordances` relation field with your own property. Change the name of your property to fix this issue.

Also, don't forget about calling the `all` method after changing the name. I assume you've removed that call because it ended up in an exception.

Comment: Yes, you're right! That was so simple at yet so sneaky.

Comment: do you know why I only get the first item from that `for` loop? When concordances are more than one I only get the first one.

Comment: Because you are returning immediately in your for loop. Instead, you should collect all the data you need in your property, join them together as you prefer and return them after the for loop.

Comment: This is empty: `list = []
            for concordance in self.concordances.all():
                for i, t in concordance.tunes.all():
                    list.append(t[i])
            return list` - something like this? I'd just like a list separated by a line break, nothing fancy.